# Roc curve plotting am I doing this right?

Tags: r, roc

I wrote my own code to create an ROC curve and then to calculate AUC from the definition but I am getting different results from other packages and I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

```
ROC.sort <- function(pred,true,vals,decreasing=FALSE){
    sorted.index <- sort(vals,index=TRUE,decreasing=decreasing)$ix
    sort.pred <- pred[sorted.index]
    sort.true <- true[sorted.index]
    return(list(sort.pred,sort.true))
}


ROC.ploter <- function(pred,true,add.to.plot=FALSE,color="black"){
    index <- which(pred == 1)
    vals <- true[index]
    n.true <- 1/length(which(vals==1))
    n.false <- 1/length(which(vals==0))
    points <- data.frame(0,0)
    last.point <- c(0,0)
    for(i in 1:length(vals)){
        if(vals[i] == 0){
            next.point <- last.point + c(n.false,0)
            last.point <- next.point
            points <- rbind(points,next.point)
        } else {
            next.point <- last.point + c(0,n.true)
            last.point <- next.point
            points <- rbind(points,next.point)
        }
    }
    if(add.to.plot){
        points(x=points[,1],y=points[,2],col=color,type="l")
    } else {
        plot(x=points[,1],y=points[,2],xlab="False Positives",ylab="True Positives",
             main= "ROC",type="l",col=color)
        points(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,1),type='l')
    }
    return(points)
}


find.auc <- function(points){
    x <- points[,1]
    y <- points[,2]
    result <- 0
    n <- length(x)
    x.prev <- x[1]
    y.prev <- y[1]
    for(i in 2:n){
        x.curr <- x[i]
        y.curr <- y[i]
        if(x.curr == x.prev){
            y.prev <- y.curr
        } else {
            result <- result + y.prev*(x.curr-x.prev)
            x.prev <- x.curr
        }
    }
    return(result)
}
```

And here is a working example.

```
library(LiblineaR)
size <- 10000
truth <- rbinom(size,1,.9)
dat <- cbind(truth+rnorm(size),truth*rnorm(size))
training.index <- (1:(floor(2*size/3)))

model <- LiblineaR(data=dat[training.index,],labels=truth[training.index])
predicted <- predict(model,dat[-training.index,],decisionValues=TRUE)

pred.labs <- predicted$predictions
pred.scores <- predicted$decisionValues

sorted <- ROC.sort(pred.labs,truth[-training.index],pred.scores,decreasing=TRUE)
pts <- ROC.ploter(sorted[[1]],sorted[[2]])
auc <- find.auc(pts)
print(auc)
```

And to create a plot with ROCR ROC curve on it and my own ROC curve on that same plot.

```
pred <- prediction(pred.scores, truth[testing.index])
perf <- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
plot(perf, col=rainbow(10))
pts <- ROC.ploter(sorted[[1]],sorted[[2]],add.to.plot=TRUE)
```

Comment: can you add a working example with this code and functions from other packages

Comment: I added a working example.  The other packages are from python and ROCR.

Comment: it looks like your example it looks like the curve is just flipped along the diagonal, so make sure you are plotting 1-spec on the x and the sensitivity on the y. And `1 - auc` and `Hmisc::somers2(truth[-training.index], pred.labs)['C']` give me approximately the same answer, so I think you just need to adjust that.

Comment: Oh crap sorry I actually do adjust it I add an extra param to ROC.sort.  But for my data it is much less smooth and has a different shape than ROCR.  I will add the commands to generate the ROCR plot.